# Encryption with public key of Notes documents using XPages (Domino 9.0.1 FP8+)

Tags: encryption, xpages, lotus-domino

Has anybody successfully encrypted Notes documents using **public** key encryption (item **PublicEncryptionKeys**) in XPages, which should be possible in IBM Domino 9.0.1 starting with Feature Pack 8 (FP8)?

I got the secret key encryption (item SecretEncryptionKeys) to work sucessfully both ways (decrypt existing documents & encrypt new/modified documents).

And I got the decryption of public key encrypted documents to work, too.

Creating new or modifying existing documents with public key encryption doesn't work. The document doesn't get saved. No errors or warning on the Domino server console.

Has anybody found any documentation about encryption/decryption of documents in XPages apps with an example using the public key encryption? Or any working sample even without documentation?

Comment: Can you post samples for the successful and unsuccessful parts? (The successful ones for delighting your fellow XPages fans)

Comment: Hi Stephan, I'll post the code, maybe in our blog, together with links to the documentation and other samples. But I try to get it working both ways and directions for now.